# How to get document DOM object from Tab object

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am writing a Firefox plugin in which I want to open a new blank page and then update its DOM content in a new tab.

The relevant call is:

```js
browser.tabs.create({url: 'about:blank'}).then(tab => {
  console.log('Tab: ' + tab);
  Object.keys(tab).forEach((prop)=> console.log(prop));
  window.document.innerHTML = '<h1>Lol</h1>';
});
```

However, this does not update the page in the new tab.
In the [official docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab) I cannot find a property of the resulting `Tab` object that I could use to get its document / DOM content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background scripts cannot access a web page. This is a work for a [content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts).